# comparing strategies to avoid flash of unstyled content (fouc)

Tags: javascript, cookies, dhtml, api-design, fouc

I need to control CSS with a cookie:

- When the user chooses a style through a control I include on all of the pages, that setting needs to persist until the user changes it or the cookie expires
- The default style nor a FOUC should occur when the user returns
- No jquery or other library or framework
- Works inIE, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari on Windows; the last four on MacOS; Safari on iOS; Firefox and Chrome on Linux)
- Bind web font used to a specific @class attribute
- Buttons shrinkwrap their text value
- Checkbox to toggle styles and show cookie state

My first strategy was to set an onload handler on the <body> element. I've seen discussion of at least two other approaches:

- `document.write` to create a <link> to a stylesheet in the <head> as the page is being built.
- [sitewizard.com](http://www.thesitewizard.com/javascripts/change-style-sheets.shtml) creates a set of small stylesheets and lets the user set one at a time to be active.

I'd be grateful for advice about choosing a strategy that is easy to code and maintain and that provides the functionality I need in the browsers I need to support.

Comment: You might try reposting this question on http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: @KevinBedell - Why are you pointing the OP to programmers? Did you read the programmers FAQ to see if it fits?

Comment: 'programmers' describes itself as the place for "professional programmers interested in conceptual questions about software development". The fact that the OP is looking "for advice about choosing a strategy" made me feel it was a better fit there. Do you disagree?

Comment: Thanks, Kevin. I cross-posted, as you suggested, and then took it down, following Oded's admonition. I didn't mean to start a debate about venues or to transgress protocol or to step on any toes; I was just hoping for a bit of programming guidance. Perhaps someone will respond here ...

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of techniques to avoid the root cause, which is [repaints and reflows](http://blog.letitialew.com/post/30425074101/repaints-and-reflows-manipulating-the-dom):

- [DOM computation](http://www.webkit.org/blog/66/the-fouc-problem/)
- [CSS source order](http://stevesouders.com/hpws/css-fouc.php)
- [Mouse events](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/window/scrollIntoView.html)
- [Inlining CSS](https://joe-watkins.io/javascript/inline-critical-css-with-wordpress/)
- [Buffer Flushing](https://www.sitepoint.com/faster-web-pages-php-buffer-flush/)
- [Minification and Concatenation](https://ikreativ.com/combine-minify-css-with-php/)
- [Lazy Loading / Deferring Scripting](https://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2010/09/30/render-first-js-second/)

**References**

- [Web Application Solutions: A Designer’s Guide](http://static.lukew.com/webapplicationsolutions.pdf)